# Unable to download the files which were uploaded to the blob storage

Tags: azure, file-upload, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have created container on azure storage and with code below made it work to upload my files(blobs) in container. Now it says upload was successful however I can't figure out how to reach those files to download it. There is no documentation on the internet about it.

Any help would be appreciated to solve it.

```
//  create Azure Storage
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=bireddy;AccountKey=8OMbjBeJR+SIYaSt0YtBUzivLKPX5ZbsGJeEY9vsX0BPbX3uy9KxOckK7LuLeH3ZbOh+NoEaiEIV/NWvZbFOrA==");

//  create a blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

//  create a container 
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// make it public
container.SetPermissions(
    new BlobContainerPermissions {
        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container
    }); 

//  create a block blob
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(FileUpload1.FileName);

//  upload to Azure Storage
//  this has to be changed sometime later

blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(FileUpload1.FileContent);
```

Grateful to your discussion.

Comment: How are you trying to access your blob? Can you share your code here? If you are trying to access it via your browser, you should be able to see your blob at http://myACC.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/first.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options to download your blobs:

Using PowerShell: See the Azure Storage Powershell guide here:
    http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-powershell-guide-full/

Using Command Line: See the documentation for the AzCopy tool here:
    http://aka.ms/azcopy

Using your C# code: There is a guide here, that includes a section on how to download blobs: 
    http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Using GUI-based explorers: There are a number of third-party explorers, some of them are listed here: 
    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/03/11/windows-azure-storage-explorers-2014.aspx

Answer (score 0):

// Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

```
        //Create the Blob service client
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named            
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference(document);

        //using (var np = File.Open(@"C:\mydocuments\"+ document, FileMode.Create))
        //    blockBlob2.DownloadToStream(np, null, options, null);
        byte[] fileBytes;
        using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blockBlob2.DownloadToStream(fileStream, null, options, null);
            fileBytes = fileStream.ToArray();
        }
        return fileBytes;
```